# Getting error -> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Tdsb.Aris.Pims.Entity.PartnershipFunding,System.String]

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enumerable

```
private string Paidby
{
    get
    {
        string paidBy = string.Empty;

        if(this.PartnershipFundingEntity!=null)
        {
            paidBy = (PartnershipFundingEntity.Where(x => x.FundingTypeId == 1).Select(y => y.CfPurposeList)).ToString();
        }
        return paidBy;
    }
}
```

receiving error like ->

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Tdsb.Aris.Pims.Entity.PartnershipFunding,System.String]

Comment: I think you are going to have to add some more details.  What is the intent of the app?  What line is throwing the error?   What have you done so far to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests an error, but the value seems to be the type name that is pushed into `paidBy` `string`:

```
paidBy = (PartnershipFundingEntity
   .Where(x => x.FundingTypeId == 1)          // where iterator at this point
   .Select(y => y.CfPurposeList))             // WhereSelectListIterator at this point
   .ToString();                               // ToString() returns type name by default
```

I think you should have something like this:

```
paidBy = PartnershipFundingEntity
   .Where(x => x.FundingTypeId == 1)
   .First(x => <boolean condition to select one element>)
   .PaidByProp;
```

This works if a single element is found, otherwise `FirstOrDefault` should be used and tested for null. I think `?.` (null conditional) can be used to narrow to a single instruction.